# Does sick day affect probation?

Tags: united-kingdom, sickness, probation

I am just one month into a 6 months probation, where my work is very tough as I am trying to catch up on a matured project with little to no help on how and where to, all I get is "look at other examples". It has send me into a worry state which is affecting my health every now and then.

Does sick day on probation affect the outcome? Given one is trying to cope up, take extra time to finish a task because he/she are new to project and help is limited. I have 1-1 with manager, he might bring all these things up. Can taking sick leave be a reason for my termination? Although my manager says in email "to take good care"

Comment: That depends on (1) jurisdiction (2) this particular company policy. Questions about both of these generally fall outside of scope of this site.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski As this is tagged "united-kingdom", it's fairly easy - your employment can be terminated for any reason or none (excluding a very small set of reasons - sex, race, etc) if you've been employed for less than two years. This falls under "stuff every HR manager will know" so I think is on topic here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It didn't have "united-kingdom" tag when I posted my comment.

Comment: @PhilipKendall As always with the UK, this is far from easy. Unfair dismissal only becomes a thing after 2 years but a wrongful dismissal or a discrimination claim doesn't have a grace period. (Summary [here](http://www.firstpracticemanagement.co.uk/blog/posts/everything-you-need-to-know-about-probationary-periods/)). And that's without even going into the possibility of the OP's employer hiding illness as a reason for a failed probation. I'm not sure there's answer that can be given here beyond "Yes it might and you have no way of knowing for sure in advance or after the fact."

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds much like your job is pushing you into depression. If your manager/team doesn't support your training and even stresses you out, there might be a better place to work, especially better for your health. Best wishes for you.

Comment: @kinea I think your comment highlight the *true problem* here. It's not about the effects of a few sick days for probation but a job causing you to need them after one month. Not that OP necessarily must quit but she has to understand the root reasons to determine if they're transitory (just some stress because of a new position? Insane working environment? Preexisting health problems exacerbated by the new job?)

Comment: How do you think taking a day off, sick or not, will solve your stress dilemma? (Assuming you already get two days off a week now.) Save personal/sick days for job hunting. The 'sink or swim' management style is lousy. All new jobs are stressful - plan an 'out strategy' (it will relieve stress), and endeavor to learn as much as you can before you go....or hang in there and ask for feedback on performance. This may or may not be a good job for you under circumstances, but if you aren't let go yet - they may see potential in work ethics, etc. Or you're doing better than it feels, perhaps.

Comment: What if this workplace uses 'sink or swim' as a misguided 'test' of how one handles stress, is resourceful in finding answers, self-motivated to find solutions? Not saying it is, just offering a different scenario to consider. Sometimes changing how we see something, changes our reaction to it. A challenge rather than persecution.

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to reference common sense, as most people in your situation forget about it:

- Your health comes first, no exceptions.
- A job is just a job, nothing personal, nothing everlasting, nothing that can't be changed
- Would you risk your health for a company that can't give new employes proper introduction to the project, and proper support to get you started? And after this, firing you for having impacts on your health?
- Would you rather be sick than fired from this job?

It't important to have a job, but its even more important to be happy and healthy. If you'r job doesn't care about your health, why should you care about your job?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for your manager. If you caught something contagious, you'd be protecting the company by taking a few days off and not spreading it; but it sounds like your issue is stress related.

Pro tip: When you look at other examples, take a few moments to compile notes on what you find. You'll start building a knowledge base which will become amazingly handy in the future, for you and other potential future hires. It'll also work wonders for your image, especially when the documentation culture tends to anarchy.

It's always a good idea to ask your manager how things are going and if you're meeting expectations, especially when you're new. Your success is your manager's success, and his job is help you do that. Asking how taking a day off or two will be perceived is perfectly pertinent.

> Can taking sick leave be a reason for my termination

<IANAL>

[Gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/dismiss-staff/dismissals-due-to-illness) states:

> Sometimes an employee may have to stop working because of long-term ill health. They may resign, or you may have to consider dismissing them
>
> [...]
>
> If the employee can’t do their job because there are no reasonable adjustments that can be made, it may be fair for you to dismiss them, even if they’re disabled

This is clearly written for cases where the employee cannot perform their duties due to long-term illness, and no reasonable accommodation can be made for them (ie. not your case).

</IANAL>

---

**tl;dr** Ask your manager

Comment: How do you imagine this conversation going? What makes you think an employer who has decided to dismiss an employee for such a potentially litigious reason as illness will actually tell their employee that?

Comment: @Lilienthal I assume the employer is reasonable and will act so. I don't imagine the manager will be very happy, but if he knows what he's doing he'll work with OP to manage each other's expectations, workload, etc. If it's policy to fire people for anything less than a hospital visit, he can warn the OP.  `We require that you bring a doctor's note`, or similar bureaucratic stuff should also be communicated.

Comment: OP's first paragraph certainly doesn't make me think their manager is reasonable or even competent. How to approach this subject with a manager would be a question all on its own since there are good and terrible ways of bringing this subject up. You'd come at it from the perspective "*I feel terrible that I'm having to take so much sick leave so early and I know it's affecting my work but this isn't normal for me and I want to do what I can to mitigate the impact.*" Not: "*You can't fire me for taking sick leave, right?*"